# How to change file names using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I am trying to rename a set of files in a folder called "The 100"

```
   The.100.The.Hundred.S04E1.HDTV.SVA.en.srt
   The.100.The.Hundred.S04E2.HDTV.SVA.en.srt
   The.100.The.Hundred.S04E3.HDTV.SVA.en.srt
```

How would I be able to change the sames to something like

```
   The 100 [S04E01].srt
   The 100 [S04E02].srt
   The 100 [S04E04].srt
```

And so on?

Comment: are all the names in the folder the exactly same format?

Comment: They all start with The.100.The.Hundred.S

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `The 100` souce directory current…

From the command line:

```bat
For %A In ("The.100.The.Hundred.S*.srt") Do @For /F "Tokens=1,2,5Delims=." %B In ("%A") Do @Ren "%A" "%B %C [%D].srt"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For %%A In ("The.100.The.Hundred.S*.srt"
) Do @For /F "Tokens=1,2,5Delims=." %%B In ("%%A"
) Do @Ren "%%A" "%%B %%C [%%D].srt"
```